# ASIHTTPRequest Socket Connection Error

Tags: ios, xcode, sockets, asihttprequest

My blog app was working fine, using ASIHTTPRequest and GDATAXML to parse the XML file.  I tried adding a Today Extension, but now it won't properly parse the XML file.  Only other changes I tried making was using Cocoapods to add a different parser to it, but I have since deleted all files that I had added.  Now all I get is:

Error: Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0x7a953f90 {NSUnderlyingError=0x79eb1180 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred}